# Django: Models values as global variables

Tags: python, django, nginx

I know that it's not a best practice (I guess caching is better way) but I saw in the code that Django model values was saved as a global variables like this in `django_app/shared.py`:

```
VALS = MyModel.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)
CHOICES = [(x,x) for x in VALS]
```

In `django/forms.py`

```
from shared import CHOICES

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    choice = forms.MultipleChoiceField(CHOICES, default='')
    ...
```

In `django/views.py`:

```
def my_view(request):
    ....
    form = MyForm(request.GET)
    ....
```

I'm running app using wsgi behind nginx. Now, the problem I see that even if I made changes in model that does not get reflected in the form on the view. The options always stay the same. Is it getting cached because uwsgi process spawns across multiple requests. I could not get it. Please help.

UPDATE: As expected that it turned out to be nginx. I restarted the nginx and changes was reflected. Now, because it was not updated without nginx restart, so does it mean that it could have stayed like that forever? My understanding was that CHOICES will get updated as soon as new uwsgi process is created. BTW, we use uwsgi conf file for configuration.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried restarting the wsgi server(Nginx)?

Comment: @EdwinLunando Please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart your wsgi server (Nginx). That should take care of the problem.

Comment: Could you quickly explain how?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing that, you can use a [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield).

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    choice = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MyModel.objects.all())
    ...
```

This would yield the below in the template:

```
<select id="id_field" name="field">
<option value="obj1.id">Object1</option>
<option value="obj2.id">Object2</option>
...
</select>
```

Comment: I cannot do that because the values are actually unique set of all the values of a field. And, it needs to display only that are in database.

Comment: Here, you will get all the `ids` which are present in the database. That will be a unique set as no 2 objects will have same `id`.

Comment: `id` is primary key so it's suppose to be unique. How about 'Employee' Model and displaying distinct last names as options? And, that should get updated according to changes in the database. So, my friend this won't work here.